# Gnuplot two x-axis from different files

Tags: gnuplot, axis

I want to plot data in a plot with two different x-axes. One should be Time in years the other one time in MJD.
This is an example from file 1 (x in years):

> ```
>     2011.27466   0.012
>     2011.71704   0.019
>     2011.71716   0.021
>     2011.87012   0.045
> ```

This is an example from file 2 (x in MJD):

> ```
>    -654.25226   0.012
>    -654.25177   0.019
>    -492.64032   0.021
>    -436.78577   0.045
> ```

Y-Values are (of course) the same.
How do I get a plot of this with x in years on the bottom and x in MJD on the top?

Comment: MJD is Modified Julian Date, in case anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `axes x2y1` to use the second, top axis:

```
set xlabel 'Time (in years)'
set x2label 'Time (in MJD)'
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics
plot 'file1.txt' using 1:2, 'file2.txt' using 1:2 axes x2y1
```